# Visual Studio 2019 Mac - Mostrar el panel donde se me muestran los archivos de los proyectos

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Se supone que del lado izquierdo se muestra un panel donde estan los archivos de codigos del proyecto que tenga en ese momento, pero sin querer le di a la equix y se quito y no se como hacer que se muestre nuevamente.

[image]

Comment: @Adrian si, lo acabo de hacer y no se muestra el panel todavia.

Comment: tenes que poner : Ver -> Panel Solucion

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias, funciono!

Answer (score 1):

@RamiroBarone, si. Funciono!

Ver=>Panel=>Solution.